# Issues when connecting to network on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: networking, google-chrome, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on my Dell Inspiron. At my school, usually there is a pop-up asking for your school username and password. It used to work just fine when I used Windows 10. However, since I installed Ubuntu, the pop-up does not appear, and it does not allow me to connect to the internet. When I try to run a command in terminal such as

```
sudo apt-get update
```

or anything else that requires an internet connection, it returns error 113 : no route to host and error 101 : network is unreachable.

According to the people at IT, the text on the bottom left corner in chrome should eventually change to "downloading proxy script", but when I try to access a webpage on chrome, in the bottom left corner, it stays on connecting, and never reaches "downloading proxy script", like it should.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Enter to Settings -> Network -> Proxy and assure that Proxy will be in Automatic

Comment: I tried that, and I also tried a few things that came up when searching "proxy not working ubuntu".